# how to get document from jsoup for the web page although is not accessible "https://www.dropbox.com/1/oath2/autorize_submit"

Tags: java, dropbox-api

```
System.out.println("1. Go to: " + authorizeUrl);
System.out.println("2. Click \"Allow\" (you might have to log in first)");
System.out.println("3. Copy the authorization code.");
```

I'm trying to implement the three steps above  to go to autheriazeUrl.
I implemented through ACTION_VIEW Intent

```
on1.setOnAction(e -> {
    DbxAppInfo appInfo = new DbxAppInfo(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
    config = new DbxRequestConfig("MotionProCapture/1.0", Locale.getDefault().toString());
    webAuth = new DbxWebAuthNoRedirect(config, appInfo);
    authorizeUrl = webAuth.start();

Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authorizeUrl))
FXActivity.getInstance().startActivity(browserIntent);
FXActivity.getInstance().finish();
```

After click allow go to have the authorize submit web page 
`https://www.dropbox.com/1/oath2/autorize_submit`.

I tried copy a and paste to clipboard, didn’t work. 
Now I want to get the document of this web page to get the code using jsoup

```
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("https://www.dropbox.com")
    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
    .data("ctl00$plnMain$txtLogin", "username")
    .data("ctl00$plnMain$txtPassword", "password")
    .data("ctl00$plnMain$Submit1", "Log In")
    .data("ctl00$ucCopyright$hdnPrivacyStatement", "Privacy Statement")
    .data("ctl00$ucCopyright$hdnTermsOfUse", "Terms of Use")
    .execute();
Map<String, String> loginCookies1 = loginForm.cookies();

Document document1 = Jsoup.connect("https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize_submit")
    .cookies(loginCookies1)
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko")
    .timeout(12000) 
    .post();

System.out.println(document1.toSTring());
```

Above code doesn’t work as it gives always the www.dropbox.com document ?
So my question how to get document using https://www.dropbox.com/1/oath2/autorize_submit
Or is that impossible, or is there a alternative that I can get the code and set it my editText?

Comment: code formatting, typos

Comment: please ask your questions more accurate

Comment: You shouldn't attempt to automate the /authorize or /authorize_submit pages. These are just meant for the user to interact with manually. When using the `DbxWebAuthNoRedirect` flow, the user needs to copy and paste the resulting "authorization code" back into the app. I recommend instead investigating why you can't "copy a and paste to clipboard".